# Inheritence and construction in one object in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am studying inheritence in C++. I am trying to take all the informations in one object "std1" (without any more func. I managed to do it with other functions). I use construction methods but it gives error constantly. Can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Employee {
protected:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string sex;
    int age;
    int ID;

public:
    Employee(){
        this->name = "null";
        this->surname = "null";
        this->sex = "null";
        this->age = 0;
        this->ID = 0;
    }
    Employee(string name, string surname, string sex, int age, int ID):name(name), surname(surname), sex(sex), age(age), ID(ID){}

    void changeInformations(string name, string surname, string sex, int age, int ID) {
        this->name = name;
        this->surname = surname;
        this->sex = sex;
        this->age = age;
        this->ID = ID;
    }


};

class Student :public Employee {
public:
    int year;
    double GPA;



    Student(string name, string surname, string sex, int year , int GPA):Employee(name, surname, sex, age, ID),year(year), GPA(GPA){}

    void printStudent() {
        cout << "Name : " << name << endl << "Surname : " << surname << endl << "Sex : " << sex << endl << "Age : " << age << endl << "ID : " << ID << endl << "Year : " << year << endl << "GPA :" << GPA << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
  
    Student std1("Kaan", "ICYAR", "M", 23, 50, 4, 3);
    std1.printStudent();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->name = "null";` probably should not exist. The default constructor of a std::string initializes a string to the empty string.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of using `"null"` as default for the strings, just let the strings be empty. It's a lot easier to check if a string is empty than to check if it contains `"null"`.

Comment: "_I use construction methods but it gives error constantly._" - What error exactly? Copy paste the full error into the question.

Comment: Here you try to construct a `Student` using 7 arguments to the constructor: `Student std1("Kaan", "ICYAR", "M", 23, 50, 4, 3);` but `Student` doesn't have a constructor taking 7 arguments.

Comment: `int age, int ID` are missing for student constructor

Comment: uh what a mistake. When i add "int age, int ID" it's working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with inheritance. `Student std1("Kaan", "ICYAR", "M", 23, 50, 4, 3);` uses the default constructor of the `Student` class, it only takes 5 arguments but you have provided 7. This is main error. And here in the constructor of `Student`, `age` and `ID` is uninitialized.

```cpp
... :Employee(name, surname, sex, age, ID), year(year), GPA(GPA) {}
                                   ^    ^
```

This means that you'll end up with two uninitialized variables.

The answer which I think what your looking for is, add `int age, int ID` into the constructor's parameters.

```cpp
Student(string name, string surname, string sex, int year, int GPA, int age, int ID) :Employee(name, surname, sex, age, ID), year(year), GPA(GPA) {}
```

Note: As some of your comment's have suggested, use the default constructor of `name`, `surname`, and `sex` rather than using "null". You can do it like follow,

```cpp
Employee() {
    this->name = {};
    this->surname = {};
    this->sex = {};
    this->age = 0;
    this->ID = 0;
}
```